# Simple refl-based proof problem in Lean (but not in Agda)

Tags: agda, theorem-proving, lean

In an attempt to define skew heaps in Lean and prove some results, I have defined a type for trees together with a fusion operation:

```
inductive tree : Type
| lf : tree
| nd : tree -> nat -> tree -> tree

def fusion : tree -> tree -> tree
| lf t2 := t2
| t1 lf := t1
| (nd l1 x1 r1) (nd l2 x2 r2) :=
    if x1 <= x2
    then nd (fusion r1 (nd l2 x2 r2)) x1 l1
    else nd (fusion (nd l1 x1 l1) r2) x2 l2
```

Then, even for an extremely simple result such as

```
theorem fusion_lf : ∀ (t : tree), fusion lf t = t := sorry
```

I'm stuck. I really have no clue for starting to write this proof. If I start like this:

```
begin
  intro t,
  induction t with g x d,
  refl,
end
```

I can use `refl` for the case where `t` is `lf`, but not if it is a `nd`.

I'm a bit at a lost, since in Agda, it is really easy. If I define this:

```
data tree : Set where
  lf : tree
  nd : tree -> ℕ -> tree -> tree

fusion : tree -> tree -> tree
fusion lf t2 = t2
fusion t1 lf = t1
fusion (nd l1 x1 r1) (nd l2 x2 r2) with x1 ≤? x2
... | yes _ = nd (fusion r1 (nd l2 x2 r2)) x1 l1
... | no  _ = nd (fusion (nd l1 x1 r1) r2) x2 l2
```

then the previous result is obtained directly with a `refl`:

```
fusion_lf : ∀ t -> fusion lf t ≡ t
fusion_lf t = refl
```

What I have missed?

Comment: Have you tried using simpl (or simp) ? I don't know much about lean but if it's anything like coq (which it looks like) it should work. I tried testing it on the web version of lean but your code is not accepted for some reason.

Comment: This doesn't work. If I try it, I get the frustrating `simplify tactic failed to simplify`.

Comment: Can you confirm that the code you provided works directly ? Can you try and use this website : https://leanprover.github.io/live/latest/ . I would very much like to see if your code works fine there.

Comment: Yes, the definitions of a tree and of the fusion function do work there (just add an `open tree` before defining fusion).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This proof works.

```
theorem fusion_lf : ∀ (t : tree), fusion lf t = t := 
λ t, by cases t; simp [fusion]
```

If you try `#print fusion.equations._eqn_1` or `#print fusion.equations._eqn_2` and so on, you can see the lemmas that `simp [fusion]` will use. The case splits are not exactly the same as the case splits in the pattern matching, because the case splits in the pattern matching actually duplicate the case `lf lf`. This is why I needed to do `cases t`. Usually the equation lemmas are definitional equalities, but this time they are not, and honestly I don't know why.